# how to define the `http client`

Tags: angular, typescript

how to define the `http client`? `this.http.post` is not working properly. Trying to send post request to get a response of jwt key from the API endpoint.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BROWSER_STORAGE } from './storage';
import { User } from './user';
import { Authresponse } from './authresponse';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

http as new HttpClient;

export class AuthenticationService {

constructor(@Inject(BROWSER_STORAGE) private storage: Storage) { }

public getToken(): String | null {
return this.storage.getItem('token1');
}

public saveToken(token: string): void {
this.storage.setItem('token1', token);
}

public login(email:string, password:string ) {
  return this.http.post<User>('http://localhost:3000/login', {email, password})
  .then((authResp: Authresponse) => this.saveToken(authResp.token));
}
```

Comment: The HttpClient needs to be injected into the constructor of the class for you to be able to use it. I suggest you read this documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Angular standard is to initialize `HttpClient` as a Typescript [parameter property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties). You could remove the `http as new HttpClient;` and add `http: HttpClient` as a constructor parameter with an accessor: `constructor(..., private http: HttpClient)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the `HttpClient` service inside your constructor

```
constructor(
  @Inject(BROWSER_STORAGE) private readonly storage: Storage,
  private readonly http: HttpClient
) {}
```

Initially you wrote
`http as new HttpClient;` which only inherits the types of `HttpClient` and applies it to your `http` variable. This will *not* create a new instance of `HttpClient`.

Comment: @Pretty_Girl I guess because you did not include a proper error message but instead just wrote "does not work properly". The more information you give the better, otherwise it's difficult for the community to help.